# What keys on my keyboard is <M-n>?

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout

Stupid I know, but I can't find for the life of me what keycombination the `<M-n>` mapping is.

- `:bn<CR>` is mapped to `<C-n>` wich is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
- `:bp<CR>` is mapped to `<M-n>` wich is ?

Comment: Type `:help <M-`

Comment: @Matt, that returns `E149: Sorry, no help for <M`

Comment: This is strange. `<M-` stands for "alt-key or meta-key". Everything is explained under `:h key-notation`. Individual topics are marked appropriately: `backspace`, `<Enter>`, `<M-` etc.

Comment: @Matt - thanks, that was the help I couldn't find. So `<M` or `<A` are both the `alt` key according to the help but my mapping `:nnoremap <M-n> :bp<CR>`  does exactly nothing. I have switched to `<S-n>` wich does work.

Comment: "Alt" works only in GUI. Also, "S-n" is just "N" and it's not the best idea to remap it.

Comment: @Matt - sigh :). You are right - switched to `<c-b>`.

Comment: That backfired pretty quickly - been using that for page-up. Anyway, thank you for your help Matt.

Comment: Try `<leader>b`, where "leader" is backslash by default. See `:h mapleader`.

Comment: @Matt - `<leader>b` is already mapped to `:ls<CR>:b<Space>`. I'm going with tab like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5563142/52598) answer.

Comment: Other typical options: `[b` and `]b` (like in vim-unimpaired) or `gb`.

Comment: @Matt - I'm using azerty. I use `[` and `]` in tmux because it's the default but as a combo, it's just to hard with azerty. You should write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The meta key is another name for the alt key. This is akin to how the Windows key is called the super key in the Linux world.

Comment: Thanks ahmed. Much appreciated.